# MVC 3 broke uncomment ctrl+k, ctrl+u in views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I don't know if is related but after installing MVC 3 RC, I can't uncomment HTML tags in the views in either WebForm Views or Razor Views. Uncomment works with javascript and C# in controllers though.

Related to Razor View installation possibly?

Edit->Advanced->Uncomment Selection is grayed out.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works pretty well for me (ASP.NET MVC 3 RC):

[image]

Make sure you have selected the entire commented text:

```
@*
<h2>@View.Message</h2>
*@
```

Comment: I've always noticed uncommenting in html has been very fickle on when it will vs when it won't

Comment: Yeah works for me in an MVC3/Razor View but have you tried it in a webforms view? Looks like it is working for me in a web form view in MVC2 or MVC3 but only when the cursor is in the middle of the comment and not when the entire comment is selected like the previous functionality. I even went as far as to disable all my VS Extensions. 

I may submit this to the MVC team to see if it's a bug. Let me know.

Comment: I'm going to say this helped me decide that it must be another extension or user setting that is causing this since MVC3 RC uncommenting works for you even though I can't figure out what is causing this. I may reset my VS user settings to determine if that's the case.